# ASP.NET MVC - So I have a bad default route - on one machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

This should not be a problem, but somehow I am getting a 'resource cannot be found' for a default route.  When I go to the IP of the site (by putting `http://1.2.3.4` in my browser), I get the error for the following route:

```
http://1.2.3.4/Home/Home
```

This is somewhat strange to me, since I do not have a 'Home' action, but rather an 'Index' action on the 'Home' controller.  I can navigate directly to other locations on the site - for example:

```
http://1.2.3.4/Products
http://1.2.3.4/Cart
http://1.2.3.4/Products/Query
http://1.2.3.4/Home/About
http://1.2.3.4/Home/Contact
```

Here are my route definitions (nothing out of the ordinary):

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I have not changed my route config.  I'm thinking that I somehow did something to my controller, but I can't for the life of me find it.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would also check the name of your views to see if that hasn't changed or you didn't inadvertently move it.

Comment: Can you share all your route definitions?

Comment: @ramiramilu see above; route config added.

Comment: did you mention any default document url in web.config or on the IIS with that /Home/Home, can you check that?

Comment: @ramiramilu this doesn't exist in either spot.  What's strange is that a) it works on my dev box, but not when I deploy; and b) it just stopped working, so I probably did do something to break it.

Comment: @EvConrad, there should be something wrong on the server which you deployed your code on. Check if there are any IIS rewrite rules on IIS? Also are you doing any inital redirects in your code? Is 'Home' is the Virtual directory name?

Comment: @ramiramilu There is no virtual directory, it is just set up as the 'Default web site'.  The files are under 'wwwroot'.  I do have some hijinx going on with redirecting in the code; if a certain configuration is not set up, a redirect to a page asking that it be set up is fired.  I'm going to pull this out.

Comment: @ramiramilu - Pulling out the RedirectToAction in my Home/Index fixed the issue.  I can push the change into the view, and use the same page instead of redirecting in the controller.  I'm pretty new to MVC so it wasn't obvious to me that I could break it this way.  Thanks!

Comment: @EvConrad, I am glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to use Route Debugger. See Phil Hackk's blog on Route Debugger

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Comment: +1 given; there was no route problem but using this and knowing about it will surely save me some grief in the future.  Thanks!